# Styling icon and text inside a button and centering it

Tags: html, css

On top is what I want, on bottom is what it currently looks like

[image]

I tried tables and divs and everything, but I cant seem to get them to center the icon and text on the button.

This is my HTML

```
<table><tr>
<td style="height:66px;">
    <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon><br>
            <span class="head-mini-text">PROPERTY</span>
        </div>
    </button>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

And my CSS

```
.head-button-size {
    height: 66px;
    width: 62px;
}
.head-material {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    font-size:50px;
}
.head-mini-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial'; 
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Any CSS gurus who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find any issue on your code and its working fine it seems. Check below snippet.

```css
.blue-bg {
  background-color: blue;
}

.head-button-size {
  height: 66px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.head-material {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.head-mini-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial Narrow', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:66px;">
      <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
            <div style="text-align:center">
              <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
              <br>
              <span class="head-mini-text">PROPERTY</span>
            </div>
          </button>
    </td>
    <td style="height:66px;">
      <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
            <div style="text-align:center">
              <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
              <br>
              <span class="head-mini-text">PROPERTY</span>
            </div>
          </button>
    </td>
    <td style="height:66px;">
      <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
            <div style="text-align:center">
              <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
              <br>
              <span class="head-mini-text">PROPERTY</span>
            </div>
          </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If this is not the problem you are looking for then share a fiddler to find what is the issue!

Comment: Thats pretty amazing - perhaps in the classes where I set colors and round corners is where the problem is - I will have a look

Comment: @torbenrudgaard i don'r think background-color and border-radius causes any issue. I just updated it and works fine. check it again.

Comment: RaJesh - actually it was - there were some strange margin and position stuff in those classes so I made new ones and check it out :-)
https://db.tt/gHmUGqeFSa

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the `<div style="text-align:center">` ;
2. Remove (now) useless `<br>` between image and text ;
3. Add those lines to `.head-button-size` rule using flexbox as written below :

**CSS code**

```
.head-button-size {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This should center the content of your button both vertically and horizontally. Then adjust the look by adding properties you want like `margin`, `padding` or by playing with the Flexbox properties. Nice doc available here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: That was some hardcore styles you use there :)  I will have to study flexbox some more, still havnt used it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this streamlined solution:

```css
.my-button {
  width:66px;
  height:66px;
  border:2px solid #154769;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#18557d;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
}

.image {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  margin:10px auto 0px auto;
}

.text {
  color:white;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  font-size:8pt;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-button">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/home-5-xxl.png"/>
  <div class="text">
  PROPERTY
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML is a lot simpler - will try it out

Comment: I found an error in the border/color classes - but your post gave me an idea to make the HTML much smaller, thanks for that :-) Now they look great
https://db.tt/gHmUGqeFSa

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this...It can help you:

```
.head-material {
color:#FFFFFF; 
margin-left:-20px;
margin-top:-20px; //add this thing and adjust as you want
font-size:50px;
 }
.head-mini-text {
color: #fff;
margin-top:20px; //add this thing and adjust as you want
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial'; 
font-size:12px;
}
```

Try doing this and tell me what happens?